# Use of HTML 5 for NFC Applications

Tags: html

I want to use HTML5 in my NFC Application,to support NFC,Should it be possible that i can achieve NFC functionality using HTML5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NFC access via some proprietary framework may be possible,nfc is possible in HTML5 in phonegap.you Should use phonegap NFC plugin.
check out this link https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc/blob/master/www/phonegap-nfc.js